# How can I switch tabs in a WinForms TabControl in designer?

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer

I have inherited code that includes a Windows Form that contains a TabControl with 5 tabs. I can't switch tabs in the designer. When I open the form in design view, the first tab is selected, and the contents of the first TabPage is displayed. When I try to switch tabs, the correct tabs at the top are selected, but only the first TabPage is displayed. I can add tabs to the control, but they don't display with an empty TabPage to work with. How can I switch tabs in the designer view so I can modify the content of the second or third TabPage?

Comment: Sounds like a bugged designer. Have you tried the tried and true approach of closing visual studio and reopening?

Comment: My crystal ball says that what *looks* like the content of the tab is actually a panel that's on top of the TabControl and its parent is the form.  So it still overlaps it when you select another tab.  Use View + (Other Windows) + Document Outline so you can see this.

Comment: I think this might be the ugliest thing I have ever seen! They don't have anything on any of the control's TabPages. Instead, they have a bunch of GroupBoxes containing all the controls, and they call BringToFront() on the appropriate one to display the 'tab' contents. Thank you @Hans Passant for the document outline tip.

Answer (score 1):

crooked-handed programmers did not foresee this :)
add prop in editor ActiveTab

```
 public class ExTabControl : TabControl
    {
        private const int TCM_ADJUSTRECT = 0x1328;
        private bool showBtn = false;
        private Message mes;


        public int? ActiveTab
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.TabPages.Count == 0 || this.SelectedTab == null)
                    return null;

                return this.TabPages.IndexOf(this.SelectedTab);
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.TabPages.Count > 0 )
                {
                    var _value = Math.Max(value ?? 0, 0);
                    var v = Math.Min(_value, this.TabPages.Count - 1);
                    this.SelectedTab = this.TabPages[v];
                }                
            }
        }


        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool ShowBtn
        {
            get => showBtn;
            set
            {
                showBtn = value;
                WndProc(ref mes);
            }

        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            mes = m;
            if (m.Msg == TCM_ADJUSTRECT && !showBtn)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Click on TabControl in WindowsForm. Go to Properties>TabPages. On the left side, you will see tabs listed, there will be 2 arrows next to them, using the arrow, take the tab you want to view/edit to the top and click Ok. This should solve your issue for now.

Comment: This method works for bugged UI nuGet packages.